# Docker, unable to run Ghost on default port 2368

Tags: docker, ghost-blog

Using Official (Docker) image from docker hub:

I was expecting this to work on the default port 2368
but localhost:2368 just hung

```
docker run -d --name some-ghost2 -v some-ghost-data:/var/lib/ghost/content ghost
```

localhost:3001 worked

```
docker run -d --name some-ghost2 -v -p 3001:2368 some-ghost-data:/var/lib/ghost/content ghost
```

Then the links in the introduction pages failed as they linked to 2368

Answer (score 0):

The fix, which took me a while to get to:

```
docker run -d --name some-ghost2 -v -p 2368:2368 some-ghost-data:/var/lib/ghost/content ghost
```

Comment: (The `-p host-port:container-port` option can't be in between the `-v` option and its `named-volume:/container-path` argument.)